What is correct computation of $\pi_1(SO_3)$ using van kampen
The following computation of $\pi_1(SO_3)$ using van Kampen is wrong:
consider the fiber bundle $S^1\hookrightarrow SO_3\to S^2$, let $E_+,E_-$ be the subbundle over hemispheres. Now $E_{\pm}\sim S^1$ as bundles over disks must be trivial, let $a,b$ be their generators. $E_+\cap E_-\sim S^1\times S^1$, with generator $c,d$ with $c$ in the fiber and $d$ in the base, the image of $c$ in $E_{\pm}$ becomes generators and $d$ in $E_{\pm}$ is nullhomotopic. Then $\pi_1(SO_3)=\frac{\langle a\rangle*\langle b\rangle}{a=b}=\mathbb Z$. Surprise...
(1) which step is wrong and why?
I suspect that $E_+\cap E_-$ is not trivial over $S^1$, it is a klein bottle so there is a relation $cdc=d$.
(2) what is the correct way? (I'm aware of the standard method using $SO_3=RP^3$, here I want to know the correct solution using van Kampen)

Which step you are unsure about? Which one lacks justification?

ok, I see $E_+\cap E_-\neq S^1\times S^1$

No, that part is correct.

Yes, the bundle is trivial over $S^1$,  because it is already trivial over either hemisphere, both of which contain $S^1$. However, this leads to two identifications $E_+\cap E_-\cong S^1\times S^1$ and these identifications are distinct. What do they differ by? The answer to this question will imply that $c$ maps to a generator over one hemisphere (depending on which identification you choose), but not over the other.

@Thorgott, I'm still confused, maybe on the other torus the generator is, say, $cd^n$, then $a=i_c,b=j_(cd^n)$, which didnt effects the result?

@EricLey If you identify $E_+\cap E_-\cong S^1\times S^1$ consistently with $E_+\cong D^2\times S^1$ and pick $c,d$ accordingly, then indeed $c\mapsto1$ and $d\mapsto a$. However, you then have to pre-compose with the transition map $S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$ of the two trivializations in order to determine the images of $c,d$ in $\pi_1(E_-)$ (spoiler: the image of $c$ won't be trivial). To get this transition map, either write down the trivializations explicitly (it helps to recognize $SO(3)$ as unit tangent bundle and use stereographic projection) or invoke abstract results.
